How do I launch a persistent Powershell session on a remote SSH'd machine?
I am using VS Code in a remote SSH'd machine, and when I close the editor, all the terminals end as well. So far, the only way I've figured out how to make them persist is to use tmux utility. I was wondering if there was a way of using New-PSSession to start a script that would still be running after I disconnect and reconnect to the machine. All the tutorials so far are showing how to use that to start a session on a remote machine, but what I want is to start a detached session on the current one. The scripts started using Start-Job also terminate as well, so that isn't the answer.

Pssessions normally persist.  $s = new-pssession machine; invoke-command $s { command }

Maybe I am asking this question wrong. Is it possible to launch a New-PSSession on the current machine without it blocking? All the examples I've seen use remote machines...
